# Changelogs for Xbox 360 Title Updates

Tags: xbox-360

There is a handful of helpful Xbox 360 geared sites, the plethora of Xbox FAQ sites, achievement guide sites, and forum sigbanner generator sites. However, there's one much more exciting one that I've never found.

Are there sites that have information regarding Xbox 360 (Retail and/or Arcade) Title updates? I'm always intrigued when I come back to a game and have to do the updates/logout/login/continue song and dance, only to be let down because I never actually know what just changed.

Comment: This has always bugged me. All software updates should have user-friendly info about what changed. Leave out the super-secret security stuff if you want, but come on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Microsoft is generally very close-guarded about Xbox 360 title updates in general. More likely than not, a large percentage of them are security and stability updates. The best resource I've found thus far to keep up with major title updates is the blog of [Major Nelson](http://majornelson.com). He's the de facto "head Xbox spokesman" at Microsoft, and seems to generally try to comment on title updates when he is able and has useful knowledge to impart. Definitely when there is news about a title update bringing big new features, Major Nelson has been amongst the first that I've seen to announce them. Major Nelson's podcast will also sometimes feature comments on title updates.

Beyond that, often individual publishers and developers have different PR plans. If you track down individual game websites, sometimes they will comment on their own title updates and what to expect from them. Often these tend to correspond with DLC releases, and so can often additional information on title updates is sometimes buried in PR releases that are sent to news sites about a game's DLC.

I don't think anything more comprehensive exists, and I'm not sure it would be allowed to exist. Certainly few gaming systems can be as usefully informative about game updates as Valve's Steam often tries to be.

Comment: A wonderfully disappointing answer that I was 100% expecting to hear. Despite that fact that I believe you 100% (and thanks for the tip on Larry Hryb, I rarely pay attention to him, maybe I'll start doing so a _little_ bit), I want to hold out another day or so for another answer.

Comment: Well, that was another day or so.

Comment: I think you are incorrect in bringing Microsoft into the changelog discussion. Microsoft has to certify the titles and title updates. It is up to the publisher/developer to publish the changelogs.

Comment: Why? Microsoft has to certify it, which means they push the buttons. If a publisher/developer gives the changelog to Microsoft, Microsoft can push the button and the text.

Comment: @Craig Nicholson: "A culture of secrecy starts at the top." Certainly Microsoft isn't the only player in the game, but they are obviously the dominant player on the 360's secrecy, given that they control the platform. As I pointed out as one clear counter-example, Steam has a platform-level changelog mechanism that isn't always used, but seems to be used more often than not, following in Valve's quite verbose examples.